# Remove while loop with precise cropping of image

Tags: javascript, image, crop

I have been staring/playing with this code for too long!

An image is cropped with `currentCrop` (x,y,width,height). `currentCrop` is precalculated based on the available dimensions the image must lie in.

`cropCentre` (x,y) is a temporary variable that stores the centre point of the crop.

`desiredPoint` (x,y) is a point in the image that is desired to be displayed, so once a crop is calculated, it would be nice to shift the image cropping so that `cropCentre` (thereby `currentCrop`) is as close to `desiredPoint` as possible, but making sure `currentCrop` does not go outside the bounds of the image.

The following code works, but I am positive the same can be achieved without any while loops:

```
if ( cropCentre.x < desiredPoint.x ) {
    while( currentCrop.x + currentCrop.width < sourceWidth && cropCentre.x < desiredPoint.x ) {
        cropCentre.x = currentCrop.x + currentCrop.width / 2;
        currentCrop.x ++;
    }
} else if ( cropCentre.x > desiredPoint.x ) {
    while( currentCrop.x > 0 && cropCentre.x > desiredPoint.x ) {
        cropCentre.x = currentCrop.x + currentCrop.width / 2;
        currentCrop.x --;
    }
}

// code for vertical omitted - if the problem can be solved for x, then the solution for y is identical...
```

Answer (score 0):

`currentCrop.x = Math.min(Math.max(desiredPoint.x - currentCrop.width/2, 0), sourceWidth-currentCrop.width)`